# Where should I save my css and js files in Symfony project?

Tags: php, css, symfony1

The docs seem unclear.I am not sure if I have to rewrite rules with apache so that their folder is staic or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the documentation is very specific about where to save your javascript & css files

You save them in `%SF_ROOT_DIR%/web/css` and `%SF_ROOT_DIR%/web/js`.

You then include them either in the `view.yml` or you include them manually on each page with `use_javascript('');` and `use_stylesheet('');`

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS and JS files are stored in web/css and web/js respectively by default. You can override these but for standard Symfony behaviour, nothing further is needed. You declare the names of the CSS and JS files to be called in the apps/frontend/config/view.yml file (or inside modules' own view.yml files to take advantage of "cascading").