# Symfony 2.2 Deployment Questions

Tags: symfony, deployment

Because of an other [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012391/symfony-2-2-white-blank-screen-in-prod-another-one?noredirect=1#comment22868578_16012391) on my server, I tried to setup a real new project and did this (localhost with xampp on windows):

- installed curl
- loader composer like told in docs
- loader vendors like told in docs
- merged app/config-folder
- copied src-folder
- copied web/bundles/myBundle-folder

After that, I tried the deployment-steps [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html). I skipped uploading the files and editing parameter.yml (it's already configured for localhost).
Than I am running into trouble doing '*B) Update your vendors*':

```
php composer.phar install --optimize-autoloader
```

This steps remove all my files from the web\bundles\myBundle-folder.

Do I have to tell composer about my bundle? I first thought, that I have to store them somewhere else, but this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380710/where-should-i-save-my-css-and-js-files-in-symfony-project) tells me, that I am right?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread you are mentioning is from symfony 1, but you are installing a symfony 2 application.

In web/bundles are your assets installed (css, javascript and images).
Your bundles which will be installed via composer are in your vendors folder.

And your own bundles should be in the src folder.

I think [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html) is a good start to have a look at where to store your files.

Your css, js and images should be stored in a bundle, e.g.:

```
src/AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/css
src/AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js
src/AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/images
```

And then you can install your assets with `php app/console assets:install web` and they will be pushed into the web/bundles folder.

Comment: Hrgh! OK, so I have to edit in src/myBundle/Ressources/... and these are then copied to web\myBundle\.... That was new to me. I worked through the 'Big picture' (and many more) and also had an project from a college as example and that didn't do it this way either. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Another small question: I now did it like told here. But this means, that changes to the file are not working in dev until I copy them (manually). Is this normal?!

Comment: You have to call `php app/console assets:install web` and if you append a `--symlink` you don't have to call that all the time you change something in your css/js.